# PyYAML YAML load_all to Objects (nicely)

Tags: python, pyyaml

I have the following Python:

```
class Instrument:
    def quandl_get(self):
        return quandl.get(self.quandl)

def yaml_load_all(name):
    with open('yaml/' + str(name) + '.yaml', 'r') as ymlfile:
        return list(yaml.load_all(ymlfile))

instruments = yaml_load_all("instruments")
```

And the following YAML:

```
!!python/object:v.Instrument
vstoxx:
    fractional_contracts: False
    multiplier: 100
    slippage: 0.0017
    per_contract_cost: 0.0211
    quandl: 'CHRIS/EUREX_FVS1'
---  
!!python/object:v.Instrument
corn:
    multiplier: 5000
    symbol: 'zc'
    months_traded: [3, 5, 7, 9, 12]
    quandl: 'CHRIS/CME_C2'
    forecasts: ['ewmac']
```

What I want is a dict of instruments, so I can do `instruments['vstoxx'].quandl_get()`.

As a bonus, I'd like to not repeat `!!python/object:v.Instrument` every time in the YAML file.

Currently I get a list of instruments. I think I need to do two steps, load the objects into a list, and then map them to a dict. Is that really the cleanest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `load_all` and multiple documents in your file (which you do by using `---`), you always get a list of separate data elements.

What you could do is change the YAML file to:

```
!!python/object:v.Instruments
vstoxx:
    fractional_contracts: False
    multiplier: 100
    slippage: 0.0017
    per_contract_cost: 0.0211
    quandl: 'CHRIS/EUREX_FVS1'
corn:
    multiplier: 5000
    symbol: 'zc'
    months_traded: [3, 5, 7, 9, 12]
    quandl: 'CHRIS/CME_C2'
    forecasts: ['ewmac']
```

(please not the topline includes an `s` at the end) and then implement a class `Instruments` that when its gets YAML loaded creates the individual `Instrument` instances and populates them, and has an attribute `self._lookup`  that stores the key-value pairs (value being the instance of `Instrument`). Then on `Instruments` create:

```
 __getitem__(self, key):
     return self._lookup[key]
```